# ajaxSubmit with json of jqueryForm

Tags: php, jquery, json

here is my ajax:

```
$('#MyUploadForm').submit(function () {

        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
            ,dataType: 'json'
            ,uploadProgress: OnProgress
            ,resetForm: true
            ,success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                if(data.error) {
                    $("#output").css('color', 'red');
                }
                else {
                    $("#output").css('color', 'green');
                }
                $("#output").html(data.msg);
                $('#submit-btn').show(); //hide submit button
                $('#loading-img').hide(); //hide submit button
                $('#progressbox').delay(10000).fadeOut(); //hide progress bar
            }
            ,error: function(xhr){
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

here is my html:

```
<form action="ss.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">
            <input name="FileInput" id="FileInput" type="file"/>
            <input name="f-name" id="f-name" type="hidden"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Upload"/>

        </form>
```

php:

```
return json_encode(array(
    'error'=> true
,'msg' => 'Invalid request!'
));
```

I am getting in error call back. I am getting this in console.log of error callback function :

```
Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="OK", more...}
```

may be i am missing something and could not find it. why it is not going inside success callback function.

Helps are appreciated

Comment: Use `echo json_encode(...)` and `die()` or just `die(json_encode(...));` insted of `return`.

Comment: what do you get in the console for (console.log(data)) ??

Comment: clarification of @marian0's comment `return` won't return data back to the browser, you should `echo` json encoded data to get response at browser.

Comment: yep -- compile your json data in a variable and do --- echo json_encode($result);

Comment: also in you JQ statement ill do -- if(data.error == "true")

Answer (score 0):

As @marian0 commented and @bansi explained it works.

Changed:

```
return json_encode(array(
    'error'=> true
,'msg' => 'Invalid request!'
));
```

to:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'error'=> true
,'msg' => 'Invalid request!'
));
```

return is not returning back the response to the browser.